# Excel VBA code for multiple vlookup

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

For a conduit network, I am trying to find the pipes that drain to a manhole. There can be multiple pipes that can drain to a single manhole. My data-structure is organized in the following way:

```
   Stop Node    Label
  .......................
    MH-37       CO-40
    MH-37       CO-40
    MH-39       CO-43
    MH-37       CO-44
    MH-39       CO-45
    MH-41       CO-46
    MH-35       CO-47
    MH-44       CO-50
    MH-39       CO-51
    MH-44       CO-52
```

and so on.

Of course, in Excel, we can workaround the multiple `vlookup` question using array equations. However, I am not sure how it is done in Excel VBA coding. I need to automate the whole process and hence Excel VBA coding. This task is part of a bigger assignment.

Following is the function code I wrote so far:

```
Function Conduitt(M As String) As String()

Dim Stop_Node As Variant /* All Manhole label */
Dim Conduit As Variant /* All conduit label */
Dim compare As Variant /* Query Manhole label */
Dim Result() As String
Dim countc As Integer

Stop_Node = ActiveSheet.Range("B2:B73").Value
Conduit = ActiveSheet.Range("C2:C73").Value
compare = M

countc = 1

Do While countc <= 72

If Application.IsError(Application.Match(Stop_Node(countc), compare)) = 0 Then

Result(countc) = Conduit(countc)

End If

countc = countc + 1

Loop

Conduitt = Result()

End Function
```

If you compare the sample of data I provided before, For Manhole `MH-39`, corresponding conduit labels are, `CO-43`, `CO-45` and `CO-51`. I thought, with `countc` changing due to `do` loop, it will go through the list and find the exact matches for `MH-39` and return `CO-43`, `CO-45` and `CO-51`.

**Objective is to return these conduit labels only as a string array** with three rows (for `MH-39` case).

So far, when I run the code, I get :

> Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range.

I searched different forums and found it happens when non-existing array elements are referenced. At this point, my limited knowledge and experience are not helping decipher the puzzle.

After some suggestions from [R3uK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30890361/excel-vba-code-for-multiple-vlookup/30891144#30891144), got the code fixed. Apparently, when a range is assigned to a variant array (as in the case of Stop_Node and Conduit), the variant will be multi-dimensional. So, updated the code accordingly and incorporated Preserve with Redim.

İn case you are interested, the updated code:

```
Function Conduitt(Manhole As String) As String()

Dim Stop_Node As Variant
Dim Conduit As Variant
Dim Result() As String

ReDim Result(0)

Stop_Node = ActiveSheet.Range("B2:B73").Value
Conduit = ActiveSheet.Range("C2:C73").Value

For i = LBound(Stop_Node) To UBound(Stop_Node)
If Stop_Node(i, 1) <> Manhole Then
Else
    Result(UBound(Result)) = Conduit(i, 1)
    ReDim Preserve Result(UBound(Result) + 1)
End If
Next i
ReDim Preserve Result(UBound(Result) - 1)

Conduitt = Result
```

Comment: Given you want to return values in 3 rows, why are you using a function instead of a subroutine?

Comment: @Raystafarian : because you can have arrays as results, so it easier to have a function for it.

Comment: DO you know at what point in you code the error occurs?

Comment: What are you trying to do with the lines Stop_Node = ActiveSheet.Range("B2:B73").Value and Conduit = ActiveSheet.Range("C2:C73").Value

Comment: @gudal In the stated code, I hit the error message once I reach the if statement. With regards to the Stop_Node and Conduit, I am copying the total list of manholes and corresponding pipes (draining to them) in the network. Objective is to find corresponding conduits of queried manhole. Thanks

Comment: Ok. That can actually be done without VBA, but when you say "automate", do you want it to do so for all manholes and then do something with/use it in another piece of code, or are you going to select manhole from a dropdown on simply view the corresponding ones?

Comment: @gudal, Yes, I want it to do so for all manholes and then do something with/use it in another piece of code. Basically, the task is to relabel all nodes in a network by a specific labelling convention. This code is part of a bigger code to map all the manholes in an U/stream to down/stream order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, you never `ReDim` your `Result()` so it is just an empty array with no actual cell (not even an empty cell), you first need to `ReDim` it.

Here is my version, I didn't use the function `Match` but that should work anyway :

```
Function Conduitt(ManHole As String) As String()

Dim Stop_Node As Variant '/* All Manhole label */
Dim Conduit As Variant '/* All conduit label */
Dim Result() As String

ReDim Result(0)

Stop_Node = ActiveSheet.Range("B2:B73").Value
Conduit = ActiveSheet.Range("C2:C73").Value

For i = LBound(Stop_Node) To UBound(Stop_Node)
    If Stop_Node(i,1) <> ManHole Then
    Else
        Result(UBound(Result)) = Stop_Node(i,1)
        ReDim Preserve Result(UBound(Result) + 1)
    End If
Next i
ReDim Preserve Result(UBound(Result) - 1)

Conduitt = Result()

End Function
```

Comment: Appreciate the quick response R3uK

Comment: @İmtiaz : No problem, did it fix your issue? If yes, plz validate answer (tick below up/down vote) to mark the question as solved!

Comment: Appreciate the quick response R3uK. I am trying to get conduit label by comparing the Stop_Node label with Manhole. Therefore, I modified your proposed code a bit and it follows:
For i = LBound(Stop_Node) To UBound(Stop_Node)
    If Stop_Node(i) <> Manhole Then
    Else
        Result(UBound(Result)) = Conduit(i)
        ReDim Result(UBound(Result) + 1)
    End If
Next i
ReDim Result(UBound(Result) - 1)

Conduitt = Result()

End Function.                                                                               However, I am still getting same error once I reach 'Else'. Regards.

Comment: Maybe try `Dim Result()` instead of `Dim Result() As String`, and if not enough, is the line with `Else` highlighted once you enter debug mode? Or is it the next one?

Comment: with Dim Result(), I get 'Compile error: Can't assign to array' and 'Conduitt =' is highlighted (blue) in line, Conduitt = Result() ı.e. line before End Function. Then, if I click OK, the debug arrow moves back to Function Conduitt......line. Maybe, its because the function output is defined as string in the Function line? I am assuming it exits before reaching the Else line. Thanks Anyways. I'll keep on looking.

Comment: Have you placed breakpoints to see how this is happening? (click in the grey area left of the code and press F5 to resume). I think that the last line should be : `Conduitt = Result`, give it a try

Answer (score 1):

Well, see you solved it, but here is an alternative solution (had to post it now that I have worked on it)

```
Function ConduittCheck(manhole As String) As String()
Dim result() As String

Dim manholeRange As Range
Dim conduittRange As Range
Set manholeRange = Range("manholes")
Set conduittRange = Range("conduitts")

Dim counter As Integer
Dim size As Integer
size = 0

For counter = 0 To manholeRange.Rows.Count
    If manholeRange.Rows.Cells(counter, 1) = manhole Then
        ReDim Preserve result(size)
        result(size) = conduittRange.Rows.Cells(counter, 1)
        size = size + 1
    End If
Next counter
ConduittCheck = result()
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks Gudal! Appreciate the help and new approach of addressing the problem.

Comment: @imtiaz : nothing really new here, same structure, just working with range instead of arrays (which will be far less efficient, as arrays are one of the key to VBA efficiency), `size` and `counter` are useless variable and furthermore `counter` starting at 0 will generate an error on the next line...